# How to copy partition table to multiple drives simultaneously

Tags: partitioning

i have 11 drives where the same partition table is needed now im using

```
sfdisk -d /dev/sda | /dev/sdb
```

how can i do it for all of them at once not one by one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
sfdisk -d /dev/sda > sda.out
for i in {b..k}
do    
    sfdisk /dev/sd$i < sda.out &    
done
```

This will start 10 `sfdisk` processes in the background, each handling one disk.

Or use `tee` with process substitution, but I can't think of a programmatic way to do it easily.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the amount of targets beforehand, you can use `tee` and process substitution to avoid intermediary files:

```sh
cd /dev
sfdisk -d sda | tee >(sfdisk sdb) >(sfdisk sdc) [...] | sfdisk sdd
```